# How to calculate the percentage of which kind the given image is after machine learning in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, vgg-net

I trained my machine with custom vgg model with CIFAR10 data set, and tested with some images in same data set.

```
airplane :  -16.972412
automobile :  -18.719894
bird :  -6.989656
cat :  -3.8386667
deer :  -7.622768
dog :  0.37765026
frog :  -8.165334
horse :  -7.4519434
sheep :  -21.241518
truck :  -18.978928
```

This is one of how I got the value of what kind the test image is. Below is what I implemented to print above:

```
kind = ["airplane", "automobile", "bird", "cat", "deer", "dog", "frog", "horse", "sheep", "truck"]
for k in kind:
      print(k,": ", output.cpu().detach().numpy()[0][kind.index(k)])
```

Here, it is correct that given test image is dog, which is the highest value, yet I want to print every values as percentage, which the sum of all is 100. How could I do this? I used pytorch for code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These values are `logits`, you should apply `softmax` on them to get the probability values between `0 - 1` and then you can multiply them by 100.

**Code Snippet:**

```
pred = output.cpu().detach().numpy()

def softmax(x):
  "Function computes the softmax values for the each element in the given numpy array"
  return np.exp(x) / np.sum(np.exp(x), axis=0)

def probability(x):
  "Function applies softmax for the given logit and returns the classification probability"
  return softmax(x) * 100

output_probs = probability(preds)
```

or you can use `softmax` function from `scipy`

```
from scipy.special import softmax

output_probs = softmax(preds)
```